# Returning more than one column in stream?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have below code:

```
 public synchronized InputStream getResourceStream(final String name)
        throws ResourceNotFoundException
    {
        if (org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isEmpty(name))
        {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("DataSourceResourceLoader: Template name was empty or null");
        }

        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try
        {
            conn = openDbConnection();
            ps = getStatement(conn, templateColumn, name);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next())
            {
                InputStream stream = rs.getBinaryStream(templateColumn);
                if (stream == null)
                {
                    throw new ResourceNotFoundException("DataSourceResourceLoader: "
                                                        + "template column for '"
                                                        + name + "' is null");
                }

                return new BufferedInputStream(stream);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ResourceNotFoundException("DataSourceResourceLoader: "
                                                    + "could not find resource '"
                                                    + name + "'");

            }
        }
        catch (SQLException sqle)
        {
            String msg = "DataSourceResourceLoader: database problem while getting resource '"
                         + name + "': ";

            log.error(msg, sqle);
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException(msg);
        }
        catch (NamingException ne)
        {
            String msg = "DataSourceResourceLoader: database problem while getting resource '"
                         + name + "': ";

            log.error(msg, ne);
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException(msg);
        }
        finally
        {
            closeResultSet(rs);
            closeStatement(ps);
            closeDbConnection(conn);
        }
    }
```

Above method return type is `InputStream`. in above i am getting column value as  `InputStream stream = rs.getBinaryStream(templateColumn);` and returning the same.
Now my requirement is i have to retrieve the value of one more column and return in the same stream along with `templateColumn`. How can i do that?

Basically in above logic i have to add one more line as below.

```
InputStream stream2 = rs.getBinaryStream(oneMoreColumn);
```

Now is it possible to return both the values in a single Stream?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could read both streams completely into a `byte[]` and return a new `ByteArrayInputStream`, but that wouldn't make any real sense because the client code wouldn't know what part of the array is your first and which part is the second stream.

Instead change your method to return an object with two `InputStream` fields.